# Late timing of `Date().getTime()`?

Tags: javascript, shiny

I'm trying to get the timing of a user's click on a dynamically-generated image using Shiny and some Javascript. The app below reports the client's time as LATER than the time captured within the server, which is not desired. I'd like to capture the time given by the user's browser when they click on the image (this will prevent noise and delays from the trip from the client to the Shiny server). Any ideas?

The ultimate goal for the app is to calculate a "find time" -- the duration it takes for a user to click on a specific coordinate after the image appears in their browser.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
options(digits.secs = 3)     # Modify and save default global time options


click.time.image.js <- "

  document.getElementById('img').onclick = function(){
      var the_time = new Date().getTime();
      console.log(the_time);
      // set input$client_time to the_time:
      Shiny.setInputValue('client_time', the_time)
}
        "

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        p("When clicking on the histogram, I'd like to capture the client-side computer's time"),
        actionButton(inputId="new_image", label= "New Image")
        ),
      mainPanel(
        imageOutput("img", click = "photo_click"),
        textOutput("client_time"),
        textOutput("server_time")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$img <- renderImage({
      input$new_image

      outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
      png(outfile, width=400, height=400)
      hist(rnorm(100))
      dev.off()

      shinyjs::runjs(click.time.image.js)

      list(src = outfile,
           alt = "This is alternate text")
    },
    deleteFile = TRUE)



    output$server_time <- renderText({
      req(input$photo_click)
      server.time <- as.character(strptime(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))    # Time with milliseconds
      paste("SERVER TIME:", server.time)
    })

    output$client_time <- renderText({
      req(input$photo_click)
      req(input$client_time)
      client.time <- input$client_time    # Time with milliseconds
      client.time <- as.POSIXct(client.time/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
      paste("CLIENTs TIME:", client.time)
    })


  }
)
```

Comment: It is not really clear from the question why you need to compare the time of the client with the one of the server. Why is it not possible to do all measurement on the client?

Comment: Do you really expect a user's browser having the correct time?

Comment: @t.niese I don't need to compare the time of the client to that of the server. However, what I do need is the most accurate/lowest "latency" time of the click -- which would almost certainly be from the client. The ultimate goal for the app is to calculate a "find time" -- the duration it takes for a user to click on a specific coordinate after the image appears.

Comment: @epascarello, I don't need accurate from the standpoint of clock time, but rather I will difference the starting client's time with the time that the user eventually clicks on it (so, e.g., wrong timezones and whatever won't matter).

Comment: `the duration it takes for a user to click on a specific coordinate after the image appears.` ok, but the client-side code knows when the image is displayed, and when the user clicks, so you can get these two moments in time on the client, and measure the difference. Why would a timestamp on the server be relevant for that?

Comment: Good point, t.niese. It isn't really important to get the timestamp on the server. Rather, I'm referencing the timestamp on the server because it seems to indicate that the timestamp I'm getting on the client is late.

Comment: @dca, what do you consider "late"? Are we talking milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours?

Comment: @computercarguy Milliseconds when I'm hosting the app on my *local* machine.

Comment: So both your client and the server run on the same machine under the same os?

Comment: @t.niese Yes, on a Mac, but just for development purposes. The ultimate app will reside on shinyapps.io, but the same issue exists when I host it there.

Comment: @dca, unless you're talking +100 milliseconds, that doesn't really matter when talking about human reaction times. An average person can only react as fast as about 250ms for most things and a super fast person is 125ms. https://www.pubnub.com/blog/how-fast-is-realtime-human-perception-and-technology/

Comment: @computercarguy. The thing that is a problem is that, in the full app, the server can cause delays (b/c it is single threaded), so I want to use the client's time (which can have its own set of issues, but for several reasons, there should be fewer issues IMO).

Comment: You also have to realize that the server has to package up the data it's going to return, send it back to the client, then the client unpack that data, and then get the time. Even on a local machine, you're talking 2-5 ms.

Comment: **1.** you can't expect the client and server time is the same when the machine or OS the client and server are running on are different even if both use NTP servers to set the time automatically. **2.** I would not expect that the time is 100% identical in the area of milliseconds between two different environments even on the same OS and machine. You would need to check the implementation to see how they handle the milliseconds.

Comment: @t.niese, Thanks! Interestingly, if I use developer tools to slow down the network on a deployed app, the server time comes in as expected later than the client's time. But with my relatively fast internet connection and no slowing down in devtools, the server comes in BEFORE the client on a deployed app.

Comment: `But with my relatively fast internet connection and no slowing down in devtools, the server comes in BEFORE the client on a deployed app.` that's nothing that I would see as something to not expect. While NTP can be rather accurate, such accuracy is normally not needed.

Comment: Again, if you want to have reliable measures only compare Timestamps from the same machine and environment. Measure the time from when the image appears on the client until the user clicks on it, on the client itself, and send that time difference with the request to the server. And if you want to, do an additional measure on the server from the point of time when the package - that will tell the client to show the image - is sent, until you receive the request from the client that you send when the image is clicked.

Comment: You also need to keep in mind that time measurements in the browser might not be accurate to prevent timing attacks. I don't know the exact details of how they try to prevent timing attacks. But that's just another reason why only timestamps of the same environment should be compared.

Comment: My most recent guess of the issue is the order of reactive renderTexts() are the source of the problem. But I'm uncertain how to change it.